# Is there a way to reset the buffer in SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I have the following record function

```
func record(sketchVM: SketchViewModel, isRecording: Binding<Bool>) {

    // MARK: 1. Create a recognizer.

    guard let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(), recognizer.isAvailable else {
        handleError(withMessage: "Speech recognizer not available.")
        return
    }

    // MARK: 2. Create a speech recognition request.

    recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
    guard let recognitionRequest = recognitionRequest else { return }
    recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true

    recognizer.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest) { result, error in
        guard error == nil else { self.handleError(withMessage: error!.localizedDescription); return }
        guard let result = result else { return }

        print("got a new result: \(result.bestTranscription.formattedString), final : \(result.isFinal)")

    }

    // MARK: 3. Create a recording and classification pipeline.

    audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    guard let audioEngine = audioEngine else { return }

    inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
    guard let inputNode = inputNode else { return }

    let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { buffer, _ in
        self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
    }

    // Build the graph.
    audioEngine.prepare()

    // MARK: 4. Start recognizing speech.

    do {
        // Activate the session.
        audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        guard let audioSession = audioSession else { return }
        try audioSession.setActive(false)
        try audioSession.setCategory(.record, mode: .default)
        try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)

        // Start the processing pipeline.
        try audioEngine.start()
        Task { @MainActor in
            isRecording.wrappedValue = true
        }
    } catch {
        handleError(withMessage: error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

It works fine except I can't reset the output from result.bestTranscription. It keeps appending to the previous recorded sound. The user wants to restart the record but we don't necessarily want to tear down all the objects and stop recording.

Is there a way to keep all the sessions, requests, engines, in place and just tell it to clear the saved recordings?

Comment: I have the same problem. I wish there was a solution.